# Can't find assertLog in org.slf4j

Tags: java, log4j2, slf4j

In my java project I use log4j.

Here example code:

```
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(Main.class);

logger.assertLog(progressBar.getMaximum() <= 100,
             "progressBar.getMaximum() > 100")
```

Nice. It's work fine.

But I want to upgrade to log4j2 and use `org.slf4j.Logger`.

So now I use this:

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

 private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(App.class);
logger.assertLog(progressBar.getMaximum() <= 100,
             "progressBar.getMaximum() > 100");
```

But now I get error:

```
Can's find symbol `assertLog`.
```

How replace `assertLog` to use in `org.slf4j` ?

Answer (score 2):

Such a method simply does not exist in slf4j nor [log4j2](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/) (nor [logback](https://logback.qos.ch/) not [flogger](https://google.github.io/flogger/) nor [tinylog](https://tinylog.org/v2/)) as such a practice would be frowned upon nowadays. In modern code it's much more common to throw when a precondition or invariant fails, and to rely on tests and actual assertions to enforce them. See e.g. Google Guava's guide on conditional failures: https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/ConditionalFailuresExplained (here are their exception-throwing utilities: [`Preconditions`](https://guava.dev/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/base/Preconditions.html) or [`Verify`](https://guava.dev/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/base/Verify.html))

Therefore your best bet is something like this:

```java
if (progressBar.getMaximum() > 100) {
    logger.warn("Progressbar exceeded 100%!")
}
```

You can totally write your own utility for this, of course:

```java
class Logging {

    private Logging() {
        // static utility class
    }

    public void assertLog(Logger logger, boolean condition, String message) {
        if (!condition) {
            logger.warn(message);
        }
    }

}
```